# Supermicro IPMI - pingable, flashable, HTTP/HTTPS not accessible

Tags: ipmi, supermicro

I have a Supermicro X9SRL-F motherboard on which the IPMI isn't working properly. When I got the board I went into the BIOS and changed the IP address to static and it shows as 192.168.x.y. The IP address is pingable but I cannot point a browser to it. IPMIView 2.21.0 detects it and I can add it to the list of devices, but I cannot conect to it that way either.

I was able to flash the firmware with a DOS boot disk and the dUpdate.exe utility successfully but none of the IPMICFG commands (-m, -list user, etc) return any data.

Also, in the BIOS I can no longer edit the IP information in the BMC/IPMI page. It allows me to enter configuration mode, but trying to navigate to any of the configurable values (IP address, netmask) automatically kicks me out of configuration mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: yup use the warranty on the board to get support